# Chef windows_package resource execution shows a "Run as" dialog

Tags: automation, chef-infra, windows-server-2003, 32-bit, silent-installer

Im trying to install SmartBear through windows_package, however when it is executing the resource, a CMD prompt says "installing service", it closes, and then a "Run As" dialog shows, of course that dialog won't go anywhere except for a user intervention.

the error raised if i click on cancel (after waiting for a while) is:

```
FATAL: Mixlib::ShellOut::CommandTimeout: windows_package[SmartBear TestExecute 9.31] (smartbear::testexecute line 61) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::CommandTimeout: command timed out:
---- Begin output of start "" /wait "C:\chef\cache\TestExecute\setup.exe" /s /sms ----
STDOUT:
STDERR:
---- End output of start "" /wait "C:\chef\cache\TestExecute\setup.exe" /s /sms ----
```

Is there any workaround for it?

Comment: Did you just delete your old question and recreate it with exactly the same text?

Comment: What is the full command line for the install? Are you missing a parameter?

Comment: @castling this is the instruction that chef is trying to run `start "" /wait "C:\chef\cache\TestExecute\setup.exe" /s /sms`. it starts the setup, but at the middle process i guess, it tries to do something with a service, and then a "Run as..." dialog is shown.

Comment: @coderanger yeah, i deleted by mistake trying to edit the title